# preg_replace appending character to match

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm looking for a way to convert a numeric into a string that could be used to represent a version.

Let's say we have

```
$foo = 123
```

I'd like to be able to convert this into `$foo = "1.2.3"`

So far I've tried

```
$foo = 123;
$string = preg_replace("[^0-9]",'$0\.',$foo);
```

But that doesn't seem do do anything at all, `$string` just comes back as empty/null.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: replace anything thats NOT 0 to 9. remove the ^ NOT

Comment: Your string doesn't match that regular expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this, ([documentation](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.wordwrap.php)):

```
$string = wordwrap($foo, 1, '.', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use [`str_split()`](http://php.net/str_split), followed by [`join()`](http://php.net/join):

```
join('.', str_split($foo));
```

Answer (score 0):

You said that it's already numeric.

```
$foo = 123;
echo implode('.', str_split($foo));
```

Answer (score 0):

^ means NOT ie [^0-9] means anything thats not in 0123456789

You also need to delimit your search using / (other characters are available)
This allows you to use modifiers (you can look that up)

You dont need to escape the replace characters either as its not a REGEX pattern

```
$foo = 123;
$string = preg_replace("/[0-9]/",'$0.',$foo);
```

Have you looked at the examples of `preg_replace()` in the php manual?
http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php